# Accessing all elements of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2d numpy array of integers, and now I want to change all the elements greater than 5 to 5.
For example,

```
[[2, 6],
 [7, 3]]
```

to

```
[[2, 5],
 [5, 3]]
```

Now, my current approach is to access all the elements using two `for` loops and then checking if each element is greater then 5, like this:

```
h, w = arr.shape[:2]
for x in range(h):
    for y in range(w):
        if arr[x,y] > 5:
            arr[x,y] = 5
```

Is there any *more pythonic* approach for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [np.clip()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) It can clip both on lower and upper value. We just pass None as lower value, to clip only on upper one.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[2, 6], [7, 3]])
>>> arr
array([[2, 6],
       [7, 3]])
>>> np.clip(arr, None, 5)
array([[2, 5],
       [5, 3]])
>>>
```